# What's the best way to URLEncode a file name in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2010, urlencode, url-encoding

My desktop application has to download a file from the internet.  The path to the file is known, the file name itself is semi variable, i.e. someone else will be putting new files there, and my application will have to download those.

Now I want to make sure that the URL is safe, and that it will be interpreted correctly.  Also, if there's a '#' in a file name (you never know), I do want it to be encoded.  Javascript has two distinct functions for this: `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`. The latter also encodes '#' characters, amongst other things.
Of course, I could roll my own, but I figured that there’s bound to be functions ready for that, and I might as well avoid making some old mistake.

I will be downloading the file with a object that uses the WinInet series of API functions ([InternetOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096.aspx) and its ilk).

So I started rummaging around on MSDN, and sure enough, there’s [UrlCanonicalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773768.aspx). But there's also [UrlEscape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [CreateUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (but that’s not present in the Delphi 2010 units), and finally [InternetCreateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which requires me to split up the entire URL.  I’d rather concatenate the first portion of the URL with the URLEncoded filename.

Also, they all have tons of different flags, different defaults which have changed over the course of the Windows versions, and I can’t figure out the differences anymore.  Does anybody know which one is best for this purpose?

Comment: The name should be %hex encoded. I don't know which function does just that though.

Comment: All the functions I mentioned in my question do that at some point.  It’s just very unclear to me which characters will get encoded with which flags, and whether all unicode characters will get encoded properly.

Comment: Beware. Just because you've received a properly encoded file name doesn't mean it's a file name you should *use*. If you receive a file name with path components, especially relative path components like `..`, you could inadvertently overwrite files you didn't expect to.

Comment: @RobKennedy: True dat.  But I’ve already sanitized it so that it doesn’t contain any invalid characters for Windows filenames, nor any path delimiters.  After all, they couldn’t have placed such files on the (Windows) server.

Comment: @user539484: Care to elaborate on that?  Why is that the one, and which flags should be used?

Comment: How does the receiver know that the Windows server is sending trustworthy data? How it even know it's talking to the server it thinks it is? Make sure you're checking the path when you receive it, not just when you send it.

Comment: @RobKennedy: When I said "I’ve already sanitized it", I meant when receiving it.  As for whether I’m talking to the right server... I’m hoping the https connection will fail if the certificate is wrong.  Even so, the contents of the received file is checked for well-formedness and validated before I start using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try the `TIdURI.PathEncode` function (located in the idURI unit) which is part of the Indy library  included with delphi.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  idURI,
  SysUtils;

Var
  FileName : string;
  Encoded  : string;
begin
  try
   FileName:='File with a Very weird f***name*#%*#%<>[]';
   Encoded:=TIdURI.PathEncode(FileName);
   Writeln(Encoded);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

This will return

```
File%20with%20a%20Very%20weird%20f%2A%2A%2Aname%2A%23%25%2A%23%25%3C%3E%5B%5D
```

Also you can take a look in the `TIdURI.URLDecode` and `TIdURI.URLEncode` functions.

Comment: Even better: PathEncode and ParamsEncode each encode their specific set of characters, and this encodes the UTF8String characters, too. Thanks, that’s what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I was looking for XD

Answer (score 2):

For the [xxm](http://xxm.sf.net/) project, I wrote my own URLEncode function:

http://xxm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xxm/trunk/Delphi/bin/public/xxm.pas?view=markup#l287